# Upload image on multiple folder php

Tags: php, file-upload, image-upload

I need to upload image into two different folders
there is my code
On first folder it is moving 
but on 2nd folder it generate exception that could not move 2nd file

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


$target_path1 = "thumbnails/";
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }
 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path1))
    {
       throw new Exception('Could not move 2nd file');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file()` has moved to the file to your `$target_path` path. So, There is nothing in your `temp`  , for second time you use `copy()`. command to upload it.

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not move file');
}
if(!copy ( $target_path , $target_path1 ))
        {  
          throw new Exception('Could not move 2nd file');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would remove temp file (`$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`) once you uploaded. You have to copy that file from first upload.

```
$success=true;
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    $success=false;
}
if($success) {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($target_path, $target_path1))
    {
        throw new Exception('Could not move 2nd file');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uploading to 2nd folder

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($target_path, $target_path1)){
     throw new Exception('Could not move 2nd file');
}
```